# Overlapping Questions

Tags: feature-request

Certain logical questions belong as well in Philosophy Stack Exchange as they do in Mathematics Stack Exchange. For example this question and this question both fall within the purview of both stackexchanges. But, the people who will read Philosophy Stack Exchange are by no means the same as those who read Mathematics Stack Exchange. Does there exist a way to make it so that questions can appear on both Stack Exchanges? If not, can that get done? If neither of those can get done, how does one communicate the question to both sets of people?

Comment: What's "this"? ${}$

Comment: I don't know if this is ironic, but this -meta- question is copy pasted. I think that it is consistent. And I think there is a case for multiple similar postings (but that case seems to be getting weaker simply by the culture here).

Comment: The issue is not really with Philosophy. If double-posting were allowed, there could be very frequent instances of double-posting for Mathematics and Physics, Mathematics and Statistics, Mathematics and Computer Science. Keeping track of answers could be very messy. A solution in some cases is to post questions on the same theme, with wording, question adjusted appropriately for the discipline.

Comment: @Mitch: Andre has it exactly right; it has nothing to do with math.SE "culture", it has to do with double-posting. In fact, in my (admittedly uninformed) opinion, Doug's question was significantly better suited to math.SE (indeed, it was just closed on philosophy.SE). This whole time, I have wanted Doug's question to exist and be open on math.SE! However, I was *even more strongly opposed* to it when a copy of the question, *identical up to minor phrasing*, existed elsewhere on the SE network. That will be the case no matter what other disciplines a question touches on, and no matter the user.

Comment: Now that the philosophy.SE copy is closed, the issue is moot. Of course, *if Doug had followed my advice and asked that the philosophy.SE copy of his question be migrated here*, your answer would be preserved on the active copy of the question, and be seen by everyone else wanting to answer Doug's question. But that is how things turned out.

Comment: By the way, I absolutely do see the case for questions on multiple SE sites that all touch on the same issue, but (and this is the key point) **they should be materially different**. It's fine if someone wants to ask a question about mathematics, and also ask about its philosophical, physical, etc. meaning / ramifications elsewhere. It is **not** fine if someone has a math question and posts it on multiple sites simply because there will probably exist people on those sites who can answer it.

Comment: @ZevChonoles: sorry. By 'culture' I didn't mean math.SE but all stackexchange sites.

Comment: @Mitch: Ah, I see. I guess I am still expecting attacks on a particular site's culture from my MathOverflow days :) In the long term, hopefully the SE team can create a technological solution that will allow questions to exist on multiple sites simultaneously (option 3 on the [post here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61539/how-should-we-deal-with-questions-that-fit-on-more-than-one-stack-exchange-site/61579#61579)) but that mod said it was unlikely.

Comment: @ZevChonoles "It is not fine if someone has a math question and posts it on multiple sites simply because there will probably exist people on those sites who can answer it." I simply don't follow.  Why in the world would you only consult one group of people on some issue instead of consulting two groups and then comparing their ideas?  I also disagree that the differences in phrasing were minor, and even if they were, it does come as possible that only minor changes in the phrasing came as appropriate.  Some overlapping questions might not need any tailoring.

Comment: @Doug: Why not? Because one group of people is significantly better suited to answering your question (namely, math.SE), and because the other group of people has stated that they are not interested in receiving questions on the topic you are asking about (see, again, the comments you received [here](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/1461) about the policy at philosophy.SE: "we should try to focus on philosophical concerns to the greatest extent possible or we will end up degrading our focus").

Comment: I take the fact that your question was closed on philosophy.SE as evidence for my contention that your question was more appropriate here (sometimes questions remain unnoticed by moderators and are not closed until they get bumped to the front page by an edit; the fact that your question remained open for so long on philosophy.SE is not necessarily evidence that it was appropriate there).

Comment: It is my personal opinion, and as I understand it, the intention of the SE team in designing these sites, that there are extremely few, if any, actual **questions** that would be appropriate on more than one SE site. Of course, there may be many *topics* or *issues* that could come up *in* questions on more than one site; but that is very far from the same thing. As Jeff (one of the SE founders) explains [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu/64073#64073),

Comment: it is in the interest of the SE network as a whole to have a policy of *not allowing* posting in more than one SE site, because otherwise people would begin posting in more and more dubiously related locations, which besides annoying everyone would decrease interest from high-powered users who no longer see a tightly focused pile of questions they are interested in answering.

Comment: @Zev: I'm a mod at Phil.SE, and as it stands now it appears the questions are *actually different* now that he's edited them. Whether this is true or not determines how we proceed. If it is (i.e., they *are* different), then we could reopen ours. If it is not true, then at least one of our users has requested his answer be migrated over, and seeing as you have no responses on your copy we could just migrate the question over and you could delete your version. Let me know.

Comment: @ZevChonoles "it is in the interest of the SE network as a whole to have a policy of not allowing posting in more than one SE site, because otherwise people would begin posting in more and more dubiously related locations..."  I don't see how anyone knows this will happen.  Jeff Atwood's comment explicitly acknowledges a "slippery slope" which implies his position as fallacious unless he establishes a chain of logical implications here, which he hasn't established.

Comment: @stoicfury: It does seem to be true that they are now different questions, though logic is unfortunately something far from my expertise so I am not completely sure myself. Again, despite my ignorance of the area, the new question on phil.SE actually still seems slightly better suited here; if the question were something like whether there were philosophical arguments favoring one set of axioms over another, I think it would be much more clear cut in phil.SE's realm. I think Doug's phil.SE question ought to be reopened; while I would prefer migrating it here, that is really up to you.

Comment: I'm going to reopen it for now. As it stands, questions purely about logic are on-topic for Phil.SE. Concordantly, I'll let it stay unless Doug specifically requests a migration.

Comment: @Doug: I'm not interested in debating this anymore. I believe that the experience Jeff and the SE team has gained in moderating communities like these has given them first-hand experience with practically every issue that could come up, and so they have likely experimentally established this. Comment on meta.SO if you would like to argue against the policy; regardless, in the future, ask on meta before posting duplicate questions on multiple SE sites, and remember, *don't post* until we reach a consensus that having the question duplicated is a reasonable course of action.

Comment: @stoicfury: Ah, given that's the phil.SE policy on pure logic questions, I can see that it is great where it is. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @ZevChonoles It wasn't a duplicate before.

Comment: @Doug: Both questions, in earlier iterations, essentially asked "why is {CqCpq, CCpCqrCCpqCpr, CCNpNqCqp} more common than other axiom sets?" and "given certain conditions, {CCNpNqCqp} is a sufficient axiom set for propositional calculus; what can we say about the length of single axioms which suffice for propositional calculus?" It is all in the edit history. By the way, I am not replying on this thread anymore.

Answer (score 12):

One way not to do it is to paste and copy a question to both sites:

1. destroying the links in the text by copying
2. without saying that you are double-posting
3. without giving the link to the other question (see below)
4. and of course, obviously, choosing philosophy as the primary site.

https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/246/overlapping-questions

Comment: A copy-pasta job. Figures why the links didn't appear here...

Answer (score 4):

Quoting [Mitch's answer](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/246/overlapping-questions/247#247) to [the corresponding question on meta.philosophy.SE](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/246):

> Cross-posting is an issue that has been addressed on stackoverflow:
>
> - [cross posting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65931/cross-posting-on-stackexchange-sites)
> - [c-p etiquette](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95615/cross-posting-etiquette)
> - [c-p rules](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87739/clarification-regarding-cross-posting-rules)
> - [c-p faux pas](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/610/cross-posting-on-different-se-sites-faux-pas)
>
> To summarize,
>
> - cross-posting (having an identical question, either by copy/paste or by an implemented mechanism in the system) is **strongly** discouraged (and a feature to implement it has been stated will not happen).
> - it is not a terrible thing to 're-ask' a question, specifically tailored to each site ("each site is autonomous"), but it is discouraged.
> - if your question turns out to just not be appropriate to the site you are posting too or is not getting the expected answers, there is a mechanism to move a question to another site (flag to a moderator and they can 'reassign' the question).